# Xcode 12 - AppName's architectures (arm64) include none that iPhone 11 Pro can execute (Intel 64-bit)

Tags: ios, swift, ios14, xcode12

Im getting AppName's architectures (arm64) include none that iPhone 11 Pro can execute (Intel 64-bit). error on Xcode 12 beta-3,

I have set below Architectures
x86_64
armv7s
arm64

how to resolve this error?

Comment: How did you solve it? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 46):

You can simply remove VALID_ARCHS, then it works.

Comment: This is correct, though I think that setting has gone from Xcode 12.  I had to load my project into Xcode 11, then remove that options (on both project and target) and then save and re-load back into Xcode 12 to get it to run.

Comment: I don't use Xcode 11. I use Xcode 12 beta , because of the In-App-Purchase-Testing feature, Xcode 11  is lacking.

Comment: Where is the VALID_ARCHS? I use Xcode 12.2 but could not find it.

Comment: @Blaszard Try your project Build Settings tab under User Defined, right near the bottom.

Comment: If your project was set up under Xcode < 12.0, and you are trying to remove VALID_ARCHS under Xcode >= 12.0, you will find the VALID_ARCHS flag in Build Settings, right near the bottom, in the User-Defined drop down. It is critical that you delete VALID_ARCHS from _both_ the project and the target.

Comment: @Mike How are you deleting the variable VALID_ARCHS? Removing the value only didn't seem to work.

Comment: @cvocvo Remove it from the project, not the target, then it will remove from the target too.

Comment: In my xcode 12.1 there is no VALID_ARCHS under User Defined section. There is only GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT and  PROVISIONING_PROFILE. Under PROVISIONING_PROFILE I can see some XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX codes (in Debug and Release sections). Are they the VALID_ARCHS they I am supposed to delete?

Comment: No. VALID_ARCHS is not PROVISIONING_PROFILE . Valid archs are x86_64 armv7s arm64.

Comment: I did not set this value.but still did not work.

Comment: Note that if the project that is causing this error is an Apple example project, it is likely that they did this because the example does not fully work in the simulator.

Comment: In my case there was a VALID_ARCHS in User Defined in the Target, not the Project. Had been working OK all day (very old app) in Xcode 12.4 and then suddenly got this error. Removing VALID_ARCHS from User Defined in the Target resolved the issue.

Answer (score 42):

Adding all architectures (x86_64 armv7s arm64) to VALID_ARCHS works. Didn't analyse more, just worked.

Comment: `x86_64` was what I needed to add to the `Debug` configuration of `VALID_ARCHS`.

Answer (score 7):

The issue could be with the scheme. Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme. Make sure that "Build Configuration" is set to "Debug" and not "Release"

Comment: Yes, you should try this if anyone still get this error. Thanks

Comment: This was what worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the issue with the instruction on this page:
https://medium.com/@khushwanttanwar/xcode-12-compilation-errors-while-running-with-ios-14-simulators-5731c91326e9

In the project file (.pbxproj) I excluded i386 and arm64 for all debug targets:

```
                EXCLUDED_ARCHS = "i386 arm64";
```

The change I made is only exclude them for simulator target:

```
                EXCLUDED_ARCHS = "";
                "EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = "arm64 i386";
```