# Error run project flutter on ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

i recently updated xcode to version 12.4, but i encountered a problem running my flutter project.

```
iPhone 12 Pro Max cannot run Runner.
Domain: IDEFoundationErrorDomain
Code: 3
Recovery Suggestion: Runner's architectures (arm64) include none that iPhone 12 Pro Max can 
execute (Intel 64-bit).
```

how to solve this problem please help me. thanks

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088106/xcode-12-appnames-architectures-arm64-include-none-that-iphone-11-pro-can-e

Comment: I can't find VALID_ARCHS in my flutter project, in that example the native ios project. help me