# Runner's architectures (armv7, arm64) include none that iPhone 11 can execute (Intel 64-bit)

Tags: ios, flutter

Today when I run my flutter(2.2.x) project in XCode Version 12.5 (12E262), shows error:

```
Runner's architectures (armv7, arm64) include none that iPhone 11 can execute (Intel 64-bit).
```

this is the UI:

[image]

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088106/xcode-12-appnames-architectures-arm64-include-none-that-iphone-11-pro-can-e) and tried to fix this problem. But I found I did not have a `VALID_ARCHS` variable in Build Settings -> User-Defined -> VALID_ARCHS.

[image]

what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: did you get solution ?

Comment: I fix it but I did not remember how to fix it right now. @Krishnakushwaha

Comment: im stuck yaar, ok thank lets see

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by updating Excluded Architectures in Project Runner

- Project Runner
- Build Settings > Architectures > Excluded Architectures

for some reason I have arm64. It works when I removed it.